# Confusion about OPTIC axis of an crystal

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, quantum-optics, crystals

Why it is essential to set a particular direction for an ***OPTICS axis** of a crystal* (e.g. Calcite)? What is the importance of that direction?

Answer (score 0):

All the physical properties of a crystal are connected to its symmetry i.e. its [point group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_point_group), and this includes birefringence. Birefringence can only occur if the point group is uniaxial or biaxial. A list of these point groups is given in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence#Common_birefringent_materials).

The optical axes are related to the principal axes of the crystal. This relationship can used in either direction i.e. you can start with a known point group and calculate where the optical axes are, or you can experimentally measure the position of the optical axes and from this you get information about the point group and the positions of the optical axes. Either way a knowledge of the optical properties is an important guide to the structure of the crystal.

Comment: So that's mean particular direction is need for mathematical calculations but the special direction has not any role on bifrienge I can just consider OPTIC axis as a single line to explain the phenomena !